# How to pause the execution in Blender Python API until I stop the running animation?

Tags: python, rendering, animation, scripting

I am currently animating a simple blanket falling over a character in Blender 3.4 using the Python API. I want to start the animation, then after a certain time (say 5 secs) I want to stop the animation and apply the cloth modifier so the blanket no longer moves across frames.

Only after stopping the animation, i want to render the image. And I am iterating through many characters in different poses but essentially doing the same blanket animation.

This is my code:

```
def animate(anim_time):

    bpy.ops.screen.frame_jump(end=False)
    bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
    bpy.app.timers.register(stop_animate, first_interval=anim_time)
    print("Exiting Animate")

def stop_animate():
    
    bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel(restore_frame=False)
    blanket = bpy.data.objects["blanket"]
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = blanket
    bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Cloth")
    print("Inside stop animate")

def render():
    # Function to generate a rendered image, save 
    # then delete characters and the scene

for i in range(0, 5):
    char = char_list[i]
    pose = choice(pose_list)
    set_scene(pose, scene_path)
    load_character(char, char_path)
    apply_pose_action(char, pose)
    add_collision(char)
    set_blanket(90)
    animate(anim_time)
    # bpy.app.timers.register(render, first_interval=anim_time*2)
    print("LAST STATEMENT")
```

It is all working fine until the render function in the last line. With bpy.app.timers.register(), Blender basically just executes the given function after x seconds but it continues executing the next statements.

What I expect is the execution in this order:

- *Inside stop animate*
- *Exiting Animate*
- *LAST STATEMENT*

What Blender does is this:

- *Exiting Animate*
- *LAST STATEMENT*
- *Inside stop animate*

Ultimately I care about the LAST STATEMENT executing at the last so it does not delete and take in a new character before generating a render. I have tried using os.wait(), a busy wait, multithreading (also with event.wait()). But all of them seem to not work or give some errors. Any help would be great!